# Non trivial massey triple product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, graded-algebras

Suppose that $(A, d)$ is graded commutative algebra with three generators $a, b, c$, each of degree $1$ and $da = db =0$, $dc = ab$. Then, how can I construct a non-trivial Massey product? What changes if the degree of $a, b, c$ changes?

Comment: What have you tried? It would help to edit your question to include the definition of a Massey product, and if you've had incorrect/incomplete ideas, write those down too and point out where they went wrong.

Comment: Also, have a look at this: [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Better questions get better answers.

Comment: @SammyBlack I just know the definitions. I am completely new to this and trying to learn by myself.

Comment: Sure, but you know lots of things! You probably know what a graded algebra is. You probably know about sign conventions in these graded algebras. You probably know *the definition of a Massey triple product*. Your post should include these things. Lots of people who know a bit of algebra and might help you, but they don't necessarily know what a Massey product is.

Comment: @SammyBlack okay, thanks for your suggestions. I do know some basic things. For now then I will delete my questions and ask again with more details.

Comment: You are also welcome to edit the question!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Typically to get a nontrivial Massey product $\langle u,v,w \rangle$, you need the products $uv$ and $vw$ to be boundaries. In your case you have just one nontrivial product being a boundary, namely $ab$. So it's conceivable that you could have a Massey product $\langle a, b, a \rangle$ or $\langle b, a, b \rangle$. I don't see other viable options. The first of these would be represented by $ac + ca$, which is zero in $A$, and similarly for the second. So there are no nontrivial Massey products here.

If you just want to mess around with things, you can try SageMath (a.k.a. Sage, "Software for Algebra and Geometry EXPERIMENTATION", emphasis on experimentation).

```
sage: # (everything after a hash mark "#" is a comment)
sage: A.<a,b,c> = GradedCommutativeAlgebra(QQ)  # define a graded commutative algebra A with three generators a, b, c. Coefficient ring is the rationals. By default, the generators are in degree 1.
sage: A.<a,b,c> = GradedCommutativeAlgebra(GF(3), degrees=(2,2,3))  # this would put the generators in degrees 2, 2, 3, respectively. Coefficient ring would be the field with 3 elements.
sage: A.<a,b,c> = GradedCommutativeAlgebra(QQ)  # back to the basic example
sage: d = A.differential({a: 0, b: 0, c: a*b})  # define a differential sending a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> a*b
sage: C = A.cdg_algebra(d)  # define a differential graded algebra C = (A, d)
sage: C.cohomology_generators(10)  # what are the algebra generators for the cohomology, up to degree 10?
{1: [a, b], 2: [a*c, b*c]}
```

There are no Massey products here.

We can produce a Massey product:

```
sage: B.<a,b,c,x,y> = GradedCommutativeAlgebra(QQ)
sage: d_B = B.differential({a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, x: a*b, y: b*c})
sage: D = B.cdg_algebra(d_B)
```

At this point, D has five generators and two nontrivial products are boundaries: $d(x) = ab$, $d(y) = bc$. So there will be a Massey product $\langle a, b, c \rangle$, represented by $xc + ay$. Let's find the algebra generators for the cohomology:

```
sage: D.cohomology_generators(10)
{1: [a, b, c], 2: [a*x, b*x, c*x - a*y, b*y, c*y], 3: [b*x*y]}
```

You can see a generator $cx-ay$ in degree 2, representing the Massey product. You can modify these examples: change the coefficient ring, change the number and/or degrees of the generators, change the differential, and see the effects.

Some of this code will be available, at least temporarily, at https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=rjfjdb, if you want to experiment.

Comment: how can you take dc =0 to produce a messy product when originally it is dc = ab.

Comment: Do you mean in the second example "B"? It's a different example, no relation to the first one. (Or if you like, starting from the first example, c has been renamed to x, and there are two new generators, one of which is now called c, the other called y.)

Comment: Yes i meant 2nd example. So essentially there is no way to construct non trivial messy triple product for a, b, c.

Comment: Yes, that's what the first paragraph says.

Comment: Okay yeah, thank you for replying. Sorry, i dont have enough "reputation" to upvote any answers yet.